# Show that $Q(\mathbb{Z}[i])$ is isomorphic to the subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ consisting of complex numbers with rational real and imaginary parts

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Show that $Q(\mathbb{Z}[i])$ is isomorphic to the subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ consisting of complex numbers with rational real and imaginary parts

In this case is "subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ consisting of complex numbers with rational real and imaginary parts" just $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ (Gaussian rationals)?

If it is, I then need to show that $Q(\mathbb{Z}[i]) \cong \mathbb{Q}[i]$.

Before I can get started, I need to know what the elements of $Q(\mathbb{Z}[i])$ look like. I know that for a ring $R, Q(R)$ is a construction which embeds R in a larger ring, giving every non-zero-divisor of R an inverse in the larger ring. What exactly does this mean for the ring of Gaussian Integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an integral domain R, Q(R) is just the ring of formal fractions with numerator and denominator in R and nonzero denominator with the usual addition and multiplication formulae.

So you must show that the (equivalence classes of) fractions

$$ \frac{a+bi}{c+di} $$

are in 1-1 correspondence with numbers $x+yi$ with rational $x$ and $y$ and that the map giving the correspondence is a ring homomorphism. The map you want is defined by rationalizing the denominator of the above expression (i.e. multiply numerator and denominator by c-di) and simplifying.

Comment: ah! Thanks! this helps alot!